# ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: lightning-aura-components, chartjs

I am trying to sets up a chart using the Chart.js library, which is uploaded as a static resource, I am getting the below error:

**ReferenceError: require is not defined throws at https://karima-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/aJdnlGe7HlLtzbzu8ssZ-A/aura_prod.js line 24 > eval:16:5**

---

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.chart}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.setup}"/>
  <canvas aura:id="chart" id="myChart" width="400" height="400"/>
```

---

```
setup : function(component, event, helper) { 
  var data = { 
    labels: ["January", "February", "March"], 
    datasets: [{ data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40] }] 
  };
  var el = component.find("chart").getElement(); 
  var ctx = el.getContext("2d"); 
  var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data); 
}
```

Comment: In the future, please edit your question if you have additional stuff to add, like code.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need [require.js](http://requirejs.org/). You'll need to download the minified version, upload it, and then include both of them:

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!join(',',$Resource.requireJS, $Resource.chart)}" ...
```